# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'

Tags: c#, sql

I can't find the error in the code but it showing me

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(" insert into" +
    " INTERVALDATA4(SerialNumber, TimeStamp, MeterData, ) " +
    "values(" + meterReading.SerialNumber + ", '" + reading.TimeStamp.ToString()
    + "'," + reading.RawReading +");", myConnection);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What is the error and how to fix it can any on me help please?
Thanks

Comment: You have an extra comma `MeterData, )`

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `INTERVALDATA4(SerialNumber, TimeStamp, MeterData, )` with `INTERVALDATA4(SerialNumber, TimeStamp, MeterData)` because you have an extra comma. I can see some extra arguments enclosed with `'` but some of them are not, if you are still having this issue try to enclose all of them with a `'`.

Anyway I would consider using `SqlParameter` to pass the parameters and not raw query because you are open to sql injection this way.

Comment: Thank you Rajmond

Answer (score 0):

To spot typos easier and avoid SQL injection, consider parameterizing your query like this:

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO INTERVALDATA4(SerialNumber, TimeStamp, MeterData) VALUES (@serialNumber, @timeStamp, @rawReading)";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@serialNumber", meterReading.SerialNumber);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@timeStamp", reading.TimeStamp.ToString());
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@rawReading", reading.RawReading);

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```